# IIS7: How to redirect folder to another within the same website in web.config

Tags: redirect, iis-7.5

I have a web.config file that I use to redirect specific pages for SEO reasons.

I want to redirect the content of one folder `www.sample.com/pro/bcn` to another folder `www.sample.com/pro/barcelona` on the same site, But I don't know how.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>      
       <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true"  httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
           <add wildcard="/forms/newsconfirmH.htm destination="/forms/NewsletterformH.htm" />
      </httpRedirect>       
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **HTTP Redirection** is installed on your server. It is not available on the default installation of IIS 7. To install it, use [the following steps](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect) (Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2):

1. On the taskbar, click Start, point to *Administrative Tools*, and then click Server Manager.
2. In the Server Manager hierarchy pane, expand Roles, and then click Web Server (IIS).
3. In the Web Server (IIS) pane, scroll to the *Role Services* section, and then click Add Role Services.
4. On the Select Role Services page of the Add Role Services Wizard, expand *Common Http Features*, select *HTTP Redirection*, and then click *Next*.

Then, put this in the web.config in the folder /pro/bcn

```
 ...
 <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.sample.com/pro/barcelona" />
 </system.webServer>
 ...
```